# Optional @PathVariable in Spring based rest call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 2.2.2 with java 1.8. I have a rest end point /getViewAnalyticsByDimension of post type. Now to accommodate a feature I need to change the api to /getViewAnalyticsByDimension/{priceAgreementId}. I want to declare path variable priceAgreementId as optional. But when I post the request to /getViewAnalyticsByDimension when there is no price agreement id from Postman it is not able to find the controller method. I can ask my frontend counter-part to send "blank" when there is no priceAgreementId and the actual priceAgreementId when it is available. But that is not elegant.

Comment: Add an additional mapping for that (on a seperate method) to handle that request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multiple request mappings for a given method. So in your case you can do something as follows to make it work with and without path variable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getViewAnalyticsByDimension", "/getViewAnalyticsByDimension/{priceAgreementId}"}")
public Object getObject(@PathVariable Optional<Object> priceAgreementId) {
   //...
}
```

If you are using a legacy version of spring you can have two different methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getViewAnalyticsByDimension/{priceAgreementId}")
public Object getObject(@PathVariable(name = "priceAgreementId") Object priceAgreementId) {
    //...        
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getViewAnalyticsByDimension")
public Object getObject() {
    //...
}
```

You can checkout https://www.baeldung.com/spring-optional-path-variables more info

Comment: Multiple request mapping did not work for me. I was forced to use 2 methods. I am using spring boot 2.2.2 & java 8. Somehow that is not supporting PathVariable Optional combination. Neither it is supporting PathVariable(required=false). It does not seem elegant to me to use 2 methods. For now have to go for this band-aid solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your method following way,

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class Test {

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/getViewAnalyticsByDimension", "/getViewAnalyticsByDimension/{priceAgreementId}"})
  public Object getObject(@PathVariable(required = false) Optional<String> priceAgreementId) {
    if (priceAgreementId.isPresent()) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
    return something;
  }
}
```

I checked both URLs accessible, (It's just an example)

> http://localhost:8888/getViewAnalyticsByDimension
>
> http://localhost:8888/getViewAnalyticsByDimension/5